# I want to sort items in array by a field with pymongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I have a table in mongodb. For example:

```
{
  "holdng_name":"MCT",
  "employes":[
     {"name":"Koroglu", "number":4},
     {"name":"Babek", "number":1},
     {"name":"Uzun Hasan", "number":3},
     {"name":"Fatali Xan", "number":2}
  ]
}
```

Now I want to sort it by "number" in this list.

Comment: Do you want to sort the employees array based on the number value of each element?

Answer (score 0):

[**$push**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) array update operator can be used with **$sort** and **$each** modifiers to get the desired results.

```
db.collection.update(
   {},
   {
     $push: {
       employes: {
         $each: [],
         $sort: { number: 1 } //-1 for descending
       }
     }
   }
);
```

**OUTPUT :** For the input docs in the question

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5d7514a3f31ae7e980dac80b"),
  holdng_name: "MCT",
  employes: [
    {
      name: "Babek",
      number: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Fatali Xan",
      number: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Uzun Hasan",
      number: 3
    },
    {
      name: "Koroglu",
      number: 4
    }
  ]
};
```

NOTE: `collection` is the target collection. And `$each` is used to emulate to push nothing to each of `employes` records for `$sort` to work.